# How to include 100% of background photo in the page

Tags: css

I've been going over some solutions here but nothing seems to fit.
my screen is using a 1920x1080 resolution and i'm creating a single page website.
I need the background photo to fill 100% of the page, BUT i also need it all the be shown. This is a photo containing a table at its bottom:

```
background-size: contain;
```

will make it shrink to a thumbnail

```
background-size: cover;
```

will make it cover the entire page and i will not see the table at the bottom.

Right now there is no actual code to show so I can't post anything here.
The actual image size is 2048x1479 so the image does not seems to be the problem

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This excellent article might help: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: this article unforunately makes your photo stretch a bit longer than it needs to. bringing it back to the same problem i asked the solution for. however, i got an answer here which got it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
body 
    {
        background-color: white;
        background-image: url('../img/background.jpg');
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

so, i've played with it some more (i've been playing with it "some more" for half an hour now) and solution has finally arrived. if someone needs the solution...^

Comment: Thanks AbbyJaneway and Pattle. it seems like the 100% of html element was also needed as written above.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background-size to '100% 100%'.

Comment: That's too superficial to say and not exactly what he was asking for. Please rewrite your answer to be more accurate and usefull.

Comment: Not trying to argue just want to understand, what was inaccurate about my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The get it to fill the whole page you would need the following CSS

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Although it may make the image appear distorted if the ratio isn't correct

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is as follow :

```
.yourMainContainerClass {

        visibility: visible;
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom:0;

        background: url(imagebc.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;

}
```

try this out ,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abtzc1eg/)**